# I need help building new dataframe from old one, by applying method to each row, keeping same index and columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-apply

I have a dataframe (df_input), and im trying to convert it to another dataframe (df_output), through applying a formula to each element in each row.  The formula requires information about the the whole row (min, max, median).

df_input:

```
            A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
2011-01-01  60  48  26  29  41  91  93  87  39  65
2011-01-02  88  52  24  99  1   27  12  26  64  87
2011-01-03  13  1   38  60  8   50  59  1   3   76
```

df_output:

```
           F(A)F(B)F(C)F(D)F(E)F(F)F(G)F(H)F(I)F(J)
2011-01-01  93  54  45  52  8   94  65  37  2   53
2011-01-02  60  44  94  62  78  77  37  97  98  76
2011-01-03  53  58  16  63  60  9   31  44  79  35
```

Im trying to go from df_input to df_output, as above, after applying f(x) to each cell per row.  The function foo is trying to map element x to f(x) by doing an OLS regression of the min, median and max of the row to some co-ordinates. This is done each period.

I'm aware that I iterate over the rows and then for each row apply the function to each element.  Where i am struggling is getting the output of foo, into df_output.

```
for index, row in df_input.iterrows():
    min=row.min() 
    max=row.max() 
    mean=row.mean()

    #apply function to row
    new_row = row.apply(lambda x: foo(x,min,max,mean)

    #add this to df_output
    help!
```

My current thinking is to build up the new df row by row?  I'm trying to do that but im getting a lot of multiindex columns etc.  Any pointers would be great.

thanks so much... merry xmas to you all.

Comment: you can use pandas method applymap. check this out https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html

Comment: thank you -  i will check that out.  Does that modify df_input in place??

Comment: No, it doesn't modify in place data

Answer (score 0):

Consider calculating row aggregates with `DataFrame.*` methods and then pass series values in a `DataFrame.apply()` across columns:

```
# ROW-WISE AGGREGATES
df['row_min'] = df.min(axis=1)
df['row_max'] = df.max(axis=1)
df['row_mean'] = df.mean(axis=1)

# COLUMN-WISE CALCULATION (DEFAULT axis=0)
new_df = df[list('ABCDEFGHIJ')].apply(lambda col: foo(col, 
                                                      df['row_min'], 
                                                      df['row_max'],  
                                                      df['row_mean']))
```